# ceph-deploy mon create-initial failed

Tags: ceph

I've tried reinstall and reconf serveral times, but it still doesn't work.

```
[ceph2][INFO  ] Running command: /usr/bin/ceph --connect-timeout=25 --cluster=ceph --admin-daemon=/var/run/ceph/ceph-mon.ceph2.asok mon_status
[ceph2][INFO  ] Running command: /usr/bin/ceph --connect-timeout=25 --cluster=ceph --name mon. --keyring=/var/lib/ceph/mon/ceph-ceph2/keyring auth get client.admin
[ceph2][ERROR ] "ceph auth get-or-create for keytype admin returned -6
[ceph2][DEBUG ] 2022-01-29 14:55:26.985 fffd688ef1e0 -1 auth: unable to find a keyring on /etc/ceph/ceph.mon..keyring,/etc/ceph/ceph.keyring,/etc/ceph/keyring,/etc/ceph/keyring.bin,: (2) No such file or directory
[ceph2][DEBUG ] 2022-01-29 14:55:26.985 fffd688ef1e0 -1 AuthRegistry(0xfffd64081ea8) no keyring found at /etc/ceph/ceph.mon..keyring,/etc/ceph/ceph.keyring,/etc/ceph/keyring,/etc/ceph/keyring.bin,, disabling cephx
[ceph2][DEBUG ] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::wrapexcept<boost::bad_get>'
[ceph2][DEBUG ]   what():  boost::bad_get: failed value get using boost::get
[ceph2][ERROR ] Failed to return 'admin' key from host ceph2
[ceph_deploy.gatherkeys][ERROR ] Failed to connect to host:ceph2
[ceph_deploy.gatherkeys][INFO  ] Destroy temp directory /tmp/tmpAkf4Uq
[ceph_deploy][ERROR ] RuntimeError: Failed to connect any mon
```

Here's my ceph.conf, my ip is 96.10.64.118

```
[global]
fsid = 84fc66f3-167b-4198-8a1d-942d16baf9a9
mon_initial_members = ceph2
mon_host = 96.10.64.118
auth_cluster_required = cephx
auth_service_required = cephx
auth_client_required = cephx

public_network = 96.10.64.0/23
osd pool default size = 1
osd pool default min size = 1
[mon]
mon_allow_pool_delete = true
```

Comment: This seems to be a fresh installation, I would recommend to get familiar with [cephadm](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/cephadm/) because ceph-deploy is deprecated for a while and has not been maintained for quite some time. You'll probably run into more issues along the way. cephadm is the default now.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common error and it happens when some parameters are missing or wrong in the `/etc/ceph/ceph.conf` file. Looking at your `ceph.conf` file, it seems your error is due to following three parameters:

- `mon_initial_members =.....`
- `mon_host =.....`
- `public_network=.....`

For network configurations and particularly public network configuration check following three options:

- [ceph-deploy mon create failing with exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482920/not-able-to-deploy-ceph-monitor)
- [ceph-deploy mon add node2 admin_socket: exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44098595/ceph-deploy-mon-add-node2-admin-socket-exception)
- [Not able to deploy CEPH monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482920/not-able-to-deploy-ceph-monitor)

Also make sure that the hostname on the server is the same in the `ceph.conf` file.

Apart from it, it can also be related to firewall like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482920/not-able-to-deploy-ceph-monitor/69424482#69424482).